# jhbuild bootstrap doesn't see brew's pixman

Tags: homebrew, osx-elcapitan, jhbuild, pixman

I'm trying to install some missing dependencies for Mac OS (10.11.6 El Capitan) following this [guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Jhbuild/Mac_OS)

There is a problem with pixman:

```
jhbuild bootstrap
```

Pixman is already installed and linked via brew, but jhbuild tries to build it anyway and fails while running 'make -j 9'.

```
***/pixman/pixman-mmx.c:100:20: error:
  constraint 'K' expects an integer constant expression
    : "y" (__A), "K" (__N)
```

I've tried options 'wipe directory and start over'/'clean'/'distclean' and also tried `jhbuild clean` before starting bootstrap all over again. It doesn't work.

In the guide they mentoned, that:

> It is also assumed that you are not using anything like brew, fink, macports, etc.

However, previously there was a similar problem with `intltool` and `jhbuild clean` & `sudo port install intltool` worked just fine.

Do you have any ideas why jhbuild doesn't recognise brew's pixman? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to fix this, but if pixman is already installed, you can just choose option 3 when building pixman to skip that module.